# Some models raise ArgumentError: Unknown validator, others finds the validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have encountered a strange error with a custom attribute validator. I had the following setup and everything worked as expected (every class is wrapped with module API and V1):

```
# app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb
class BusinessAccount
  has_many :transactions, class_name: BusinessAccountThings::Transaction
end

# app/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction.rb
module BusinessAccountThings
  class Transaction
    belongs_to :business_account
    validates :amount, money: true
  end
end

# app/validators/api/v1/money_validator.rb

class MoneyValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless /^\d+\.*\d{0,2}$/ =~ value.to_s
      record.errors[attribute] << 'Only two digits are allowed.'
    end
  end
end
```

I now want to use the custom validator in `BusinessAccount`, like this:

```
class BusinessAccount
  has_many :transactions
  validates :current_balance, money: true
end
```

I then get the following error when running the spec for `BusinessAccount` (and a similar error when trying to load the class from Rails console):

```
/home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:120:in `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'MoneyValidator' (ArgumentError)
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:117:in `block in validates'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:113:in `each'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:113:in `validates'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction.rb:22:in `<class:Transaction>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction.rb:5:in `<module:BusinessAccountThings>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction.rb:3:in `<module:V1>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction.rb:2:in `<module:API>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:16:in `<class:BusinessAccount>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:4:in `<module:V1>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:2:in `<module:API>'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /home/hannes/workspaces/rails-app/spec/models/api/v1/business_account_spec.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/hannes/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Line 16 in `BusinessAccount` is `has_many :transactions, class_name: BusinessAccountThings::Transaction, dependent: :destroy`

Line 22 in `Transaction` is `validates :amount, money: true`.

If I remove Line 22 from `Transaction`, the problem disappears.

If I run my spec for `Transaction`, I get this error:

```
1) API::V1::BusinessAccountThings::Transaction 
   Failure/Error:
     validates :current_balance,
               numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 },
               money: true

 ArgumentError:
   Unknown validator: 'MoneyValidator'
 # ./app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:9:in `<class:BusinessAccount>'
 # ./app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:4:in `<module:V1>'
 # ./app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:2:in `<module:API>'
 # ./app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/api/v1/business_account_things/transaction_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # NameError:
 #   uninitialized constant API::V1::BusinessAccount::MoneyValidator
 #   ./app/models/api/v1/business_account.rb:9:in `<class:BusinessAccount>'
```

So it appears as if both classes cannot load the `MoneyValidator` at the same time... How can I solve this?

Comment: could you post complete spec which is failing?

Comment: Sure I can, but I don't think this has anything to do with my specs since I get the same error in console. Do you still think it's relevant? Or is there any particular part of the spec you want to see? The spec for `Transaction` is pretty short, but the one for `BusinessAccount` is over 100 LOC...

Comment: To me it looks like autoloading `API::V1::MoneyValidator` fails. `business_account.rb` is trying to load it as `API::V1::BusinessAccount::MoneyValidator`. I guess it would work if your validator would be a top-level constant, i.e. without `API::V1`.

Comment: First suggestion: If you only need one API version running at the same time, consider ditching the `API::V1` nesting and either just do the versioning declaratively or move your code into a folder `./app/api/v1/` and add that to the load path.

Comment: Second suggestion: Maybe you can solve your problem by giving a hint to the autoloading (either the Rails Way or the Ruby Way). See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: @Raffael I agree, it looks like the autoloading does not work. I'll try to ditch the namespace for the validator and see if it's working. I rather keep the namespace on the rest of the classes though.

Comment: That did the trick! If you take your first comment and write it in an answer, I'll accept it. Now, the only question is why the autoloading fails in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoloading `API::V1::MoneyValidator` fails with your setup.

`business_account.rb` is trying to load it as `API::V1::BusinessAccount::MoneyValidator`. That fails because it is namespaced under `API::V1`, not `API::V1::BusinessAccount`.

Autoloading will also try to find `MoneyValidator` (without namespace; as written in the source code). So if you move your validator class out of the `API::V1` namespace and make it a top-level constant, then it should work.